# Copy password2 field automatically from password field in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make my sign up form simples.
I want to hide the password2 field and copy the value entered in password field automatically to password2 field. I tried a javascript but it did not work.
This is what i tried.

```
<td><span class="smalltext">{$lang->password}</span></td>
<td><span class="smalltext">{$lang->confirm_password}</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="password" class="textbox" name="password" id="password" style="width: 100%" /></td>
<td><input type="password" class="textbox" name="password2" id="password2" style="width: 100%" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="display: none;" id="password_status">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<script>
$(function(){
    var $foo = $('#password');
    var $bar = $('#password2');
    function onChange() {
        $bar.val($foo.val());
    };
    $('#password')
        .change(onChange)
        .keyup(onChange);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input` event will handle all events that modify value, including pasting, typing, etc. so I would recommend that over trying to capture all other possible events

```js
const passwordInput2 = document.querySelector('#password2');
document.querySelector('#password').addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  passwordInput2.value = event.target.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="password" class="textbox" name="password" id="password" style="width: 100%" />
<input type="password" class="textbox" name="password2" id="password2" style="width: 100%" />
```

Comment: That solved it. Thanks a lot @Eric Phillips